# Excel return all values from another worksheet column that meets criteria

Tags: excel, vba

So i am developing this access sheet for agents daily usage. The principle is that data is entered in "Access Sheet" tab and for daily usage "Search" tab is used which return values from access sheet based on vlookup search.

[SEARCH tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZnBX.jpg)

[ACCESS SHEET tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP4rj.jpg)

What i need is that below search results table, values that meet criteria `cellvalue<(Now()-25)` at "Access Sheet" tab column `J` would be returned additionally with information from same rows columns `E` and `I`. And a hyperlink like in search table column `D`.

Formulas i have used in SEARCH sheet to get the search working are:

in table column `C`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('ACCESS SHEET'!$A6,'ACCESS SHEET'!$B6:$L$997,COLUMNS('ACCESS SHEET'!$E6:'ACCESS SHEET'!E6)+3,FALSE),"")
```

in table column `H`:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP('ACCESS SHEET'!$A6,'ACCESS SHEET'!$B6:$L$997,COLUMNS('ACCESS SHEET'!$E6:'ACCESS SHEET'!J6)+3,FALSE),"")="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP('ACCESS SHEET'!$A6,'ACCESS SHEET'!$B6:$L$997,COLUMNS('ACCESS SHEET'!$E6:'ACCESS SHEET'!J6)+3,FALSE),""))
```

In all other table cells except columns `C` and `D` there are the same formulas

In column `D` there is a hyperlink based on `vlookup` result:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#'ACCESS SHEET'!E"&MATCH(C7,'ACCESS SHEET'!$E:$E,0),"Click Here"),"")
```

In "access sheet" tab there are formulas only in gray zone columns and they are `search(C)` and `rank+countif(B)`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: Hello, sorry if i was not clear enough. I want to automate the process in `SEARCH` tab so values from `ACCESS SHEET` column `J` called `Last Accessed` that meet criteria `cellvalue<(now()-25)` (i have made this as a conditional formatting in that column so it turns orange and means that this system needs attention) would be automatically returned to `SEARCH` tab under the search results table along with the system name, access status and hyperlink to the row it returned. Date in column `J` is entered automatically by checking the check box